# Prove Bessel functions of the first kind of integer order are linearly dependent from the gamma function form

Tags: gamma-function, bessel-functions

I got one of the proof that Bessel functions of the first kind of integer order are linearly dependent from [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bessel_Function_of_the_First_Kind_of_Negative_Integer_Order). However, it proves from the integral form of the Bessel function.

How can I prove

$${J_{-n}}(x) = (-1)^{n} \, J_n(x)$$

starting from

$$J_{\alpha }(x)=\sum _{m=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{m}}{m!\Gamma (m+\alpha +1)}}{\left({\frac {x}{2}}\right)}^{2m+\alpha}$$

I can't get the equation to show linearly dependent by replacing $\alpha$ with $-\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using
$$ J_{\nu }(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k}}{k! \, \Gamma(k+\nu +1)} \, \left(\frac {x}{2}\right)^{2k+\nu} $$
and properties of the gamma function then for $\nu = n$:
\begin{align}
J_{-n}(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k}}{k! \, \Gamma(k-n+1)} \, \left(\frac {x}{2}\right)^{2k-n} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac {(-1)^{k}}{k! \, \Gamma(k-n+1)} \, \left(\frac {x}{2}\right)^{2k-n} + \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k}}{k! \, \Gamma(k-n+1)} \, \left(\frac {x}{2}\right)^{2k-n} \\
&= 0 + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k+n}}{(k+n)! \, \Gamma(k+1)} \, \left(\frac {x}{2}\right)^{2k+n} \\
&= (-1)^n \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k! \, \Gamma(k+n+1)} \, \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{2 k +n} \\
&= (-1)^n \, J_{n}(x).
\end{align}

Comment: Is $\Gamma(x) = \pm \infty$, where $x$ is a non-positive integer, valid?

Comment: @IvanaGyro  yes, $\Gamma(-n)$ give infinities for $n$ being a positive integer.